# How to make <msxsl:assembly href="" dynamic

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, msxsl

I am using script in `xslt`

```
<msxsl:script language ='C#'>
     <msxsl:assembly='c:\mydll.dll' />
```

How can i define the path of dll dynamically or configure the path of dll or relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the relative path from `xslt` file

```
<msxsl:assembly='../mydll.dll' />
```

Path is not relative to application, path is relative to `xslt` file